# Transmuting non-static mutable reference into static mutable reference inside a scope within the lifetime

Tags: rust, scope, lifetime, transmute

Following code ([playgroung](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=af5f46d22e2f5e6df685a822e9997e65)) works with miri, but is it free of undefined behavior?

```
use std::thread;

fn f1(x: &'static mut f64) {
    *x += 1.0;
}

fn f2(x: &'static mut f64) {
    *x *= *x;
}

fn f3(x: &'static mut f64) {
    *x = (*x).log10();
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1.0f64, 9.0, 100.0];
    let funcs = vec![f1, f2, f3];
    let a_mut = a.iter_mut().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    thread::scope(|s| {
        for (x,f) in a_mut.into_iter().zip(&funcs) {
            s.spawn(|| {
                f(unsafe{std::mem::transmute::<_,&'static mut f64>(x)});
            });
        }
    });
    println!("a -> {a:?}");
}
```

In this code, a non-static mutable reference is sent to a function taking a static mutable reference as input, using a transmute. However, execution is constrained to a scope within the lifetime of the mutable reference.

---

Similar question with `Fn(&'static mut f64)` [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=221f6c3e0554512737e03d417ce8962f)

```
use std::thread;

fn f1(x: &'static mut f64) {
    *x += 1.0;
}

fn f2(x: &'static mut f64) {
    *x *= *x;
}

fn f3(x: &'static mut f64) {
    *x = (*x).log10();
}


fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1.0f64, 9.0, 100.0];
    let funcs = vec![
        &f1 as &(dyn Fn(&'static mut f64) + Send + Sync),
        &f2 as &(dyn Fn(&'static mut f64) + Send + Sync),
        &f3 as &(dyn Fn(&'static mut f64) + Send + Sync)
    ];
    let a_mut = a.iter_mut().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    thread::scope(|s| {
        for (x,f) in a_mut.into_iter().zip(funcs) {
            s.spawn(|| {
                f(unsafe{std::mem::transmute::<_,&'static mut f64>(x)});
            });
        }
    });
    println!("a -> {a:?}");
}
```

---

---

Note: Although my question was about the change of lifetime, the example is a bit artificial since it can be rewritten without transmute, as Chayim mentions, simply by defining `fn f1(x: &mut f64)`, `fn f2(x: &mut f64)` and `fn f3(x: & mut f64)`, instead of `fn f1(x: &'static mut f64)`, `fn f2(x: &'static mut f64)` and `fn f3(x: &'static mut f64)`.

Comment: I hope in your real use case there is an actual reason for the `transmute()`, since here there isn't.

Comment: Thank you! In my actual project, it is about futures instead of threads. I have imposed static references because of that. But I am still executing futures within the variable's lifetime, in particular by using `async-scoped`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lifetimes can never affect behavior](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/231). This is not documented in an official place as far as I know, unfortunately, but this is the general conception.

If you hand those references to unknown code, that would be *unsound*, but assuming all code is known and doesn't actually use the reference outside of its lifetime, this is fine.

Comment: Thank you, you've answered my question perfectly, although I illustrated it with a bad example!